# How does the swing system work?

Tags: ios, tiger-woods-pga-tour-12

I just got Tiger Woods PGA Tour 12 for my IPod.  I am having trouble understanding the swing/aiming system

*Example 1*

- **Lie:** Fairway 98%
- **Club:** 7 iron
- **Aim Marker:** Right on the hole and it says 96%

In this scenario:

- Is the Swing meter already set up for 96% to be the max or should I stop close to the bottom ~96%?
- Does this include the roll or the in-air only distance?

*Example 2*

- **Lie:** Rough 65%
- **Club:** 7 iron
- **Aim Marker:** Right on the hole and it says 87%

Again if my understanding is the bottom of the swing is 100% and that number is 140yds, 87% of that would be about 120.  So am I 120 from the hole?  Now if I am in Rough 65% does that mean I need to hit a shot equivalent to about 184yds?

So far so good, but now lets say there is a trap in front of the hole then I need to fly the ball all 184yds (then backspin it) so should I hit a club that goes something like 200yds? Because the 184 might be 160 in the air and land it the trap.  This is where I confuse myself.

Last question.  Does my swing speed have any impact on the distance in this game?

I know it is part of learning the clubs but I want to make sure I have the theory down correctly first.